# Background Asihttp requests

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, asihttprequest

I need to submit multiple json datas(say 10) to the server using asihttp request .
These 10 files are stored in my cache folder.when the requestfinished delegate get called i remove the corresponding file from the cache folder . It works fine in my current view . But i have to wait for sometime. I need to perform this task in background and move to another viewcontroller  But it causes crash due to the delegates methods being called of the past view.
How can i fix this problem.Help me if any idea.

Comment: I've had this issue on one of my projects before, and the answer there was to not use ASIHTTPRequest. Unfortunately, its just not designed for scenarios where the delegate making the request can disappear before the request itself disappears.

Comment: Can you post the crash logs and the relevant source code?

Comment: @DavidDoyle then what is the alternative you used to fix this issue..??

Comment: I used NSURLConnection and its block-based method to essentially reimplement ASIHTTPRequest

Comment: You may use blocks with ASIHTTP too, [see here](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/How-to-use#using_blocks). But apart from that, ASIHTTP is not longer maintained by its author. So in any case I'd consider switching libraries.